# I am new to those stuff i have to do a quadratic equation for school

Tags: c++, equation, quadratic

I have to make a quadratic equation in Microsoft Visual Studio.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    float a, b, c, D, x1, x2;
    printf("Type in a :\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &a);
    if (a == 0)
    {
        printf("The equation is not quadratic");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Type in b:\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &b);
        printf("Type in c:\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &c);
        D = b*b - 4 * a*c;
        if (D < 0)
        {
            printf("There are no real roots");
        }
        else if (D == 0)
        {
            x1 = x2 = -b / (2 * a);
        }
        else
        {
            x1 = (-b + powf(D, 0.5)) / (2 * a);
            x2 = (-b - powf(D, 0.5)) / (2 * a);
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I have done till now. Can you tell me where is my mistake? The studio isn't finding any mistakes, but there is a problem - after starting the program I type in a, b, and c and after that it says : "Press any key to continue" and when I do the console window disappears. Pls help

Comment: you need to print the solution, then wait for any input from the user....

Comment: Do you want it to actually print the roots? You never tell it to do that.

Comment: This doesn't look like C++, it looks like C.

Comment: how about.. `printf("press any key to continue");` ... then `scanf_s(whatever);`

Comment: You really should test whether `scanf` succeeds or fails. Also, I suggest `sqrt` instead of `pow(x, .5)`, and why not go for `double`-precision? Finally, I really advice you to stay clear of `scanf_s` and such.

Comment: @self: It is C++, what's your beef with it?

Comment: @Deduplicator not taking advantage of anything C++ has to offer.

Comment: @self: I see `float`, `printf`, `system`, loads of stuff. Please say how that's not C++. Also, you really want to suggest someone should write C on a MS-compiler?

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm just saying at first glance i don't see any distinct C++ features being used when you compare it to C

Comment: @self: I see MSVC, that's enough to say it won't be C (99% surety).

Comment: This would compile as a C program, as is, do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not printing the answer . . . for each case (real roots or not) you need to add a printf to print the calculated values of x1 and x2.

The line "pause" is the line that causes the "Press any key to continue . . . " so your program is reaching that point without error.